# Ember component life cycle hook method - Is it mandatory to call super?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my project some of the Component life cycle hook methods don't have `this._super(...arguments)` such as `didReceiveAttrs`, `didUpdateAttrs`, `didRender`, `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement`.
but I didn't face any issue. should I change to include or not ?

I know if we override `init` for a framework class like `Ember.Component`, be sure to call `this._super(...arguments)` in our init declaration! If we don't, Ember may not have an opportunity to do important setup work, and we'll see strange behavior in your application. ([ref](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_init))

Comment: Change and include it, should the hooks behaviour be modified in the future you will have to go back and add them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not **mandatory** to call `this._super` **always** for every single life cycle hook. However, sometimes you need it and sometimes you don't. Bugs that are caused by the lack of the `_super` call when it was actually necessary results in bugs that are usually difficult to spot or debug. Therefore, the recommendation is to always call it, to stay safe. If you call it and it isn't needed, it will do nothing, so you lose nothing for doing it.

I guess it is one extra line of code, but it really has no downside, except the 5 seconds that it'll take you to type it.

For a related conversation see:
[Deprecate the usage of Ember.on for Component's lifecycle events.](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/174)