# How to find out when all child components were rendered?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have to know when all child components will be rendered in my parent component. I could create observer in parent component and set property in child component in hook didRender. But maybe could anyone advice more graceful way?

Comment: parent component didRender hook will be called only after all the child component didRender completed. so you can write required code in parent component didRender hook without worrying child component is rendered or not since that will be always rendered before parent component.

Comment: @kumkanillam, yes, you are right. My child components was built in wrong way because it retrives data from server and when data were loaded ember rerenders the component but in this case `didRender` isn't fired in parent component.

Comment: Which ember version you are?.. child component property change will trigger didRender of the parent component  from ember version 2.10 onwards. [refer my question and twiddle to confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606056/5771666)